# Returning object from ArrayList incorrectly involving custom exceptions

Tags: java

I am trying to return a BankAccount object from String accountNumber. I was told that there was an issue with my loop but I've tried all kinds of loops but no dice. With my introduction to custom exceptions, it certainly has thrown me for a loop.

My BankingFirm class

```
ArrayList < BankAccount > bank = new ArrayList < BankAccount > ();

public BankAccount displayBankAccount(String accountNumber) throws InvalidAccountNumberException {
 BankAccount bnum = null;
 if (accountNumber != null && accountNumber.length() >= 7) {
  for (BankAccount k: bank) {
   if (k.getAccountNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(accountNumber)) {
    bnum = k;
    break;
   } else {
    System.out.println("invalid account number");
   }
  }
  return bnum;
 } else {
  throw new InvalidAccountNumberException(accountNumber + " is not a valid account number");
 }
}
```

This is my custom exception class.

```
public class InvalidAccountNumberException extends Exception {
 public InvalidAccountNumberException(String message) {
   super(message);
 }
}
```

And in my Driver class, I create a new BankingFirm object to call the method in my try/catch block using scanner input.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

try {
 String in = input.next();
 obj.displayBankAccount( in );
} catch (InvalidInvoiceNumberException ex) {
 System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
}
```

When I return bnum, it carries over to the else statement and prints out "invalid account number" instead of the object details. Hope everything makes sense. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I found the issue here

```
public BankAccount displayBankAccount(String accountNumber) throws InvalidAccountNumberException {
    BankAccount bnum = null;
    if(accountNumber != null && accountNumber.length() >= 7) {
        for(BankAccount k:bank) {
            if(k.getAccountNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(accountNumber)) {
                bnum = k;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(bnum);    //this works
        return bnum;
    }else {
        throw new InvalidAccountNumberException(accountNumber + " is not a valid account number");
    }
}
```

I added a bunch of System.out.println() everywhere and found that works but when I `return bnum;` nothing happens.

Comment: We know what your method does, because you've posted its code (which is good). But what we don't know (and have to guess) is what it **should** do. What's the contract of this method? How would you describe what it's supposed to do (when the account is present, when the account is absent, when the given number is too short)?

Comment: What is the input you are giving?

Comment: The input is an account number given from user input. There are BankAccount objects created in the Driver with account numbers. If accountNumber is not found, print a message saying that. If accountNumber != null and is longer than 7 characters - display the object details (like account number, name, balance), else throw the custom exception if the entered account number is less than 7 chars or is null. Does that help?

Comment: OK. So, what does your method do when an account is not found? It returns null, right? So your driver class should check for null, and print a message saying that the accound was not found. And you should remove the `else` clause from your method: this else clause prints a message for every account in the conllection that doesn't match the account number. You don't want that, right?

Comment: Oh I see, that's why it continued to loop after the object was found and print the else statement for every account. I added the break; after because of it. The issue is that the object is found but returns nothing (other than that else statement). So is the object not being stored in bnum?

Comment: If the account is not found, your methid returns `bnum`, and the value of `bnum` is its initial value: null.

Comment: I updated my post. The account is found but when I return it, nothing happens.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when returning bnum? What do you think returning something from a method does? I think you're confusing "printing" and "returning".

Comment: Ohhh. That makes so much sense now. I added this :
System.out.println(obj.displayBankAccount(inv));
to my try catch block and removed the syso in the method. Now the method does what it should do. Thank you so much!